# Creating a Bullish engulfing candle script

Tags: pine-script

Just getting started with Pine Script and coding in general. I found a couple open source scripts that was able to signal a buy when there is an engulfing bullish candle. Is there a way to code it so that there has to first be 3 bearish candles and then a bullish candle to signal the buy? Image 1 shows what I am wanting with 3 red candles then signal a buy. Image 2 shows that there was only 1 red candle and then there was a bullish candle that signaled a buy.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vepsW.png
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwMMI.png

Comment: You haven't linked any images

Comment: Interesting it was showing up earlier let me edit that. Thank you so much!
Didn't know I had to put a ! in front of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threeRed = close[1] < open[1] and close[2] < open[2] and close[3] < open[3]

oneRed = close[1] < open[1]

bullishEng = close > open and close > max(open[1], close[1])

buySignal1 = oneRed and bullishEng and not threeRed
buySignal3 = threeRed and bullishEng
```